# What's a word for "feel-good financial returns"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests

first post here. I'm trying to describe in a casual, off-the-cuff way that by investing in sustainable businesses we can make both "feel-good" and "financial returns."

The sentence structure goes like this - "the transition to a sustainable economy will create incredible feel-good and financial returns."

I like the ring of "feel-good" but realize that it doesn't quite make sense because there's no such thing as a "feel-good return."

Does anyone have suggestions that would be grammatically clearer, but still sound conversational and fun? Or, feedback that the sentence is fine as is? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think there's no such thing as a "feel-good return"? I think that's exactly what they're describing, which is that the investment improves your state of mind, in addition to the state of your bank account.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it a *social return*.

> Social return on investment (SROI) is a principles-based method for measuring extra-financial value (i.e., environmental and social value not currently reflected in conventional financial accounts) relative to resources invested.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_return_on_investment)

It's part of what has come to be known as ESG:

> Environmental, social and governance (ESG) refers to the three central factors in measuring the sustainability and ethical impact of an investment in a company or business.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental,_social_and_corporate_governance)

Here's an example of the term in use:

> When Nonprofits Become Market Innovators, Social Returns Are Exponential
>   [- Stanford Social Innovation Review](https://ssir.org/articles/entry/when_nonprofits_become_market_innovators_social_returns_are_exponential)

In your example, you might consider investing businesses that you believe would yield *social and financial returns*.